# How to design REST API with Twisted?

Tags: web-services, api, rest, twisted

I'm planning to design some REST APIs with Twisted in Python.  For example, I want to use the HTTP method "GET" to fetch a single user's information:

```
GET http://myhost:8000/api/v1.0/users/[user_id]
```

I know I should inherit the twisted.web.resource.Resource and implement "getChild" by myself. The question is, should I implement a class for each segment of the URI? If so, I have to implement class API, class V1, class Users and Class User. In other words, if there're 10 segments in the URI, do I have to implement 10 classes to represent those resources?

Comment: Please do not include version in URL. Versioning should be done via headers.

Answer (score 1):

I also ended up asking myself that question. Although there may be more suitable solutions for REST designs in python, like [flask](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/), I'd prefer a `twisted` solution since a big part of my application is already built on top of it.

So I stumbled over the [txrestapi](https://github.com/iancmcc/txrestapi) project. It defines a single resource class (`APIResource` in `txrestapi/resource.py`) for routing requests to registerd callbacks using regular expressions. With the use of regular expressions you also get named parameters like `[user_id]` for free.

Note: The txrestapi project seems to be abandoned, so it might not work with newer versions of twisted. It is however a useful example for implementing a REST-friendly resource class with regular expressions.

Comment: I tried that, but there were compatibility issues and it is not actively maintained.

Comment: You don't really have to use this exact library. I'm just saying that you can use it as a reference implementation since it is pretty small/simple. Just use regular expressions and you don't have to create 10 subclasses as indicated in the question.

Comment: I know, I just mentioned it, in case someone stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been trying to do this and [klein](https://github.com/twisted/klein), seemed like a good option. It is built on top of twisted and provides high level abstractions for RESTful services.
It also supports deferreds.